# Update DB row in codeigniter, by id

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to update a row in DB using ID. I realized you could do it through the URI SEGMENT But there is another way as the variable $ GET. For some reason it fails to update.

Another question, why when I do the URI SEGMENT IF it does not work? Sample code: if ($ this-> uri-> segment (3)) === false) ...

For some reason, the condition does not work. Thank assistants.

the model:

```
public function updata_user($data) {

 $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->db->update('users', $data);



}

}
```

the controller:

```
public function save() {



    $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->hash($this->input->post('password'),TRUE)


    );

    if ($this->uri->segment(3) === false) {

        $this->users_model->insert_user($data);
        redirect('users/index');


    }


    else {


        $result = $this->users_model->updata_user($data);

        if ($result) {


            redirect('users/index');


        }


    }



}
```

the view:

```
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('users/save'); ?>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('name', set_value('name', $user->name)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('email', set_value('email', $user->email)); ?></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><?php echo form_input('id', set_value('id', $user->id)); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><?php echo form_password('password'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Confirm password</td>
    <td><?php echo form_password('password_confirm'); ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>


    <td></td>
    <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: You can use get or post method to send id data.

Comment: or pass the uri segment as argument function save($id){}

Answer (score 1):

You can put id in hidden input and using $this->input->post('id') you can using that in model

View

```
<tr>
<td>id</td>
<td><?php echo form_hidden('id',$user->id); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Model

```
    public function updata_user($data) 
    {
    $this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('id'));
    $this->db->update('users', $data);

    }
```